# Descarga de archivos servidor FTP

Tags: java, ftp, servidor

alguna recomendacion? mi cliente recibe el "archivo" pero no hace ningun metodo para aceptarlo, mi cliente solo envia el comando para hacerlo ejecutar en el server.

esta es mi metodo download en mi clase comandos

```
    public void download (String filename){
        File f = new File(path + filename);

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Starting");
        System.out.println(">>Sending File : "+ filename + "  " );
        System.out.println(">>Please wait...");
        try{if(f.exists()){
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Server.s.getInputStream() + path + filename); //linea 87
          BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(Server.s.getOutputStream());
          BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
               while(true){
               byte[] buffer = new byte[1024] ;
               int i = bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
               if (i == - 1) {
                   break;
               }
               bout.write(buffer, 0, i);
               bout.flush();
               }
   }
```

este es el error que me da al ejecutarlo

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
java.net.SocketInputStream@521e4820
C:\Users\Eduardo\Desktop\Eduardo\Uru\Clases Programacion\POO\CLI\cesar.txt 
(El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at eagz.org.Commands.download(Commands.java:87)
at eagz.org.Menu.menu(Menu.java:52)
at eagz.org.ConexionServer.run(ConexionServer.java:15)
```

este es mi clase cliente

```
package eagz.org;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cliente {
static int PORT = 9000;
static String IP = "localhost";
static Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

public static void main(String[] args){ 
    try {
        while(true){
        Socket s = new Socket(IP, PORT);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("-- Client Side --");
        System.out.println("Connecting to Server -> " +  IP  + "/" + PORT);
        System.out.println("Designated Commands: "+"->Create "+"->Read" + "->Rename "+"->Delete "+"->Download "+"->Upload");
        System.out.println("C:>");
        String commandmsg = input.nextLine();
        oos.writeObject(commandmsg);
        Object servermsg = ois.readObject();
        System.out.println("From Server :"+ servermsg);
        oos.close();
        ois.close();
        }   
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Usar espacios en los paths de tus aplicaciones Java es la receta para el sufrimiento :)

Answer (score 1):

Fijate bien en la `URL` de quieres leer los datos:

> "java.net.SocketInputStream@521e4820
>   C:\Users\Eduardo\Desktop\Eduardo\Uru\Clases Programacion\POO\CLI\cesar.txt"

No me sorprende que este ruta no puede existir.

Tu código erróneo es:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Server.s.getInputStream() + path + filename);
```

No estoy seguro si quieres construir el `FileInputStream` de `Server.s.getInputStream()`, pero estoy seguro que no va funcionar con las dos al mismo tiempo. Así dependiente de que quieres como ruta de fuente puedes usar:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Server.s.getInputStream());
```

o

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path + filename);
```

o en este caso aún más simple:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
```

como ya probaste si esta ruta existe.